# Marquee effect with collapsing toolbar android

Tags: android, marquee, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am working on an android application and using collapsing toolbar in layout.
Now, the title of collapsing toolbar can be long enough, so it will be truncated when I will show a long title.
The title shows with 3 dots when the collapsing toolbar is expanded and the same when it is collapsed.
So, what I want is the title should be shown with marquee effect when the collapsing toolbar will be collapsed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="@dimen/collapsing_tool_bar_margin_end"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="@dimen/event_profile_collapsing_tool_bar_margin_bottom"
        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBar.TitleText"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TransparentText"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/toolbar_expanded_title_margin_start">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/cover_image_and_video_display_height"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/cover_image_layout">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/coverImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/cover_image_and_video_display_height"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                style="@style/CoverTitleView"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
                android:shadowDx="1"
                android:shadowDy="1"
                android:shadowRadius="2"
                android:id="@+id/cover_content_title"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/title_font_size"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:typeface="monospace"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:singleLine="true" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/slidingTabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/home_icon_tab_height"
            app:tabMaxWidth="@dimen/tab_max_width"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            style="@style/CustomTabLayoutStyle"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="@dimen/padding_3dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/dark_divider"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Please check the code above in which I am setting the collapsing toolbar title in textview with id cover_content_title when the collapsing toolbar is expanded and using the textview with id toolbar_title inside Toolbar when the collapsing toolbar is collapsed.

I have applied marquee properties on textview with id toolbar_title, so that marquee effect on title will be working when the collapsing toolbar will be collapsed.

I am using the below code to detect collapsing toolbar is expanded or collapsed

```
 @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {

        if(collapsingToolbar.getHeight() + verticalOffset < 2 * ViewCompat.getMinimumHeight(collapsingToolbar)){
// Collapsed
            mToolBarTitle.setText("Marquee effect with collapsing toolbar working")       
            mToolBarTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
// Expanded
            mToolBarTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

The textview get display when I collapse the collapsing toolbar but it shows the truncated title of textview even I have applied marquee properties on it.

Can you please help where I am doing wrong so that I can get it working.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: did you get answer? I am also looking for same..if you can help